# How to count the pixels in an image using Qimage

Tags: c++

This is my code so far, I am pretty useless at this and cannot seem to find much help on the web. 
I am looking to count the pixels of the value 0xff7a2080 from the image and then display the amount in main before saving it as a specific file name. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
unsigned TotalPixels (int width, int height)
{

 int pixelcount;
 int QImage:: width (QCoreApplication) const;
 int QImage:: height (QCoreApplication) const;

 {
  pixelcount = width * height;
  }

  return pixelcount;
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
const char LogoFile[] = "RGUMoodleLogo.png";

unsigned PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];     // Image loaded from file

// If the file cannot be loaded ...
if (!loadImage(PixelGrid, LogoFile))
{
    // Display an error message
    cout << "Error loading file \"" << LogoFile << "\"" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "File \"" << LogoFile << "\" opened successfully" << endl;

    if (saveImage(PixelGrid, "RGUMoodleLogoCopy.png"))
    {
        cout << "File \"RGUMoodleLogoCopy.png\" saved successfully" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not save \"RGUMoodleLogoCopy.png\"" << endl;
    }

}



return a.exec();
```

}

Comment: where exactly do you use QImage?

Comment: I am not even sure how to use QImage at the moment, is there a simpler way to count pixels without using this function?

Comment: so you want to count the number of pixels in PixelGrid that have the value 0xff7a2080?

Comment: yes, well at least i think that is what is being asked. The original question is this: This function should be passed the 2D matrix and a colour value as parameters. It
should return a count of the number of pixels in the image which are of that colour
(that is, their value matches the parameter). Call this function in the main program
and display the count of the number of pixels with the value 0xff7a2080 in the image.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that came to my mind (adapting to your style)

```
unsigned countPixels(unsigned pixels[][HEIGHT], long value) {
    unsigned count = 0;

    for(long x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        for(long y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
            if(pixels[x][y] == value)
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

usage: `std::cout << countPixels(PixelGrid, 0xff7a2080) << std::endl`

Comment: C:\Users\owen\Desktop\Graphics\main.cpp:8: error: declaration of 'pixels' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
 unsigned countPixels(unsigned pixels[WIDTH][], long value) {
                                             ^   
this is the error code that i get when implementitng your code. Thanks a bunch for the help!!!

Comment: please see my edit. you should also try to understand the code before using it

Comment: its proving more difficult than i expected, however I am getting there slowly. Thanks anyway